# Can't see image after it is drawn Java

Tags: java

So i created a Java program witch background is an image. However, i cant see the image when it is drawn. I dont get any errors and i really dont know what the problem is. The code of the main class is:

```
        Image image;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("287463.jpg").toURI()));
        ImagePanel ip = new ImagePanel();
        ip.setBackgroundImage(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code of the class with the drawing code is:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private Image bgImage;

public Image getBackgroundImage() {
   return this.bgImage;
}

public void setBackgroundImage(Image image) {
   this.bgImage = image;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage( bgImage, 0, 0, bgImage.getWidth(null), bgImage.getHeight(null), null );
}
```

}

Im sorry if the question is incredebly stupid by the way, im new to using images in java. Thnx in advance!

Comment: You don't show the `ImagePanel` `ip` being added to a Container (like a `JFrame`) that's being displayed. Are you doing that?

Comment: I doubt it; the `ip` variable goes out of scope immediately.

Comment: i see, you guys are right. didn't add it to the JPanel, thnx for the reply's